# List all variable defined in bc command

Tags: bc, symbol-table

Is it possible to list all variables (print symbol table) in `bc` command?

For example

```
$ bc -q
x=3
y=4
z=x+y
/* a command for listing all variables defined */
/* and it will show:
  x 3
  y 4
  z 7
  or maybe in other format */
```

If saying "all defined variable" is ambiguous, "all non-zero variables" should also be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

##### No, no such command exists in `bc`.